# "Symbol not found: _getentropy" error after updating command line tools on yosemite

Tags: python, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

I recently created a python application which trawls through Bing and saves the pages as PDF's using WKHTMLTOPDF, it was built using Py2APP.

Everything was working perfectly and as I wanted it to do until I updated Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for Xcode.

Now whenever I try to run the app it instantly crashed and i get the following error:

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 70 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _getentropy
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/EnglishSearch.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x00007fff63035075 dyld_fatal_error + 1
1   dyld                            0x00007fff630382a8 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 180
2   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8c2983ba dyld_stub_binder + 282
3   ???                             0x00000001040af190 0 + 4362793360
4   org.python.python               0x000000010400d0b8 _Py_InitializeEx_Private + 375
5   org.pythonmac.unspecified.EnglishSearch 0x00000001000024ac 0x100000000 + 9388
6   org.pythonmac.unspecified.EnglishSearch 0x000000010000117a main + 650
7   org.pythonmac.unspecified.EnglishSearch 0x0000000100000be4 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8db0c232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8dc5b26e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8db0b94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8941a3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8db0b94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8941a3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8db0b94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8941a3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff6306d288  rbx: 0x0000000100200390  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007fff6306d3f0  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfd290  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfd278
   r8: 0x00007fff63057b4c   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fff6305afb6  r11: 0x00007fff6306d3f0
  r12: 0x0000000000000018  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fff6306d3f0  r15: 0x0000000104130188
  rip: 0x00007fff63035075  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010009c000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3
```

I've searched around online and it seems to be a problem with CommandLineTools. I think this to be the case because I tried running the exact same app on my other laptop which hasn't been updated in a while and it worked.

My version of Xcode is 2339 and the Path is /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Does anyone out there know how to fix this error?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Mac has an inbuilt version of python that it needs. The command line tools may well update and alter this version of python. If you want to develop applications it's best to use a python that's independent of the operating system. Try installing python from an external source, such as using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). This will install *another* python on your system that is only used by you, so you can update it and add libraries to it without worrying about command line tools altering it.